Sketch comedy skit from 70s/80s where man gets same traffic violation almost every day for a year?
We are looking for an old sketch comedy skit (my mom thinks from the 70s or 80s) where a man goes into a police station because he keeps getting the same traffic violation ticket over and over. He gets one every day except Sundays and holidays for a year.
He deals with a female police officer who acts very dumb about the situation, asking him a ton of questions. 
My mom is pretty sure that in the end, she arrests him.
We need to know what show it came from, name of the skit, actors in it... anything to identify it, or even better a link to it if its on YouTube or something.

Can your remember any details about the actors in the sketch or the venue, e.g., Red Skelton Show, Carol Burnett, etc. Any other identifying details would be helpful.

Also, what country did the show appear to be from? US? UK? Canada? Elsewhere?
